# Repetitive Output for Shiny renderText

Tags: r, shiny

The following code can be copied and pasted into RStudio and run:

```
salary <- c(45434,54834, 685485)
name <- c("john smith", "willy mcghee", "john paul stevens")
df <- data.frame(salary, name)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Title 
  titlePanel("title"),
     # this is the sidebar on the left when you run 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        # selection of names
    selectInput("people",
            label = "select the investor",
            choices = c("john smith", "willy mcghee", "john paul stevens"))
       ),
   mainPanel(
      helpText("main panel text"),
      textOutput("textsummary")
   )
 )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   vals <- reactiveValues()
 observe({
   vals$people <- input$people
   vals$famousNetWorth <- df %>% filter(name == input$people)
} )

 output$textsummary <- renderText({
   paste(" the salary for ",vals$people, " is ",   vals$famousNetWorth)
    })
  }
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

**Question**
Why does the output print twice (highlighted in yellow)? The problem definitely stems from trying to select the value from the `salary` column in my `df` to match the user selected 'name',except I'm struggling to find a better way to reactivity pick the salary that matches with the input of `name`. The next picture is hard coded-- this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a shiny issue. Try printing this and see if it's what you expected: `paste("salary:", df %>% filter(name == "john smith"))`

Comment: The same double output occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurred (as @greg L mentioned in the comments) the output of the `filter` step is still a `data.frame` with two columns as in the original 'df'.

```
df %>% 
    filter(name == "john smith")
#  salary       name
#1  45434 john smith
```

Using `paste`, it goes through each column and `paste` the 'salary:' string with the column value

```
paste("salary:", df %>% 
                  filter(name == "john smith"))  
#[1] "salary: 45434" "salary: 2"
```

If we look at the second case, it looks perplexing, but check out the `str` of the 'df'

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ salary: num  45434 54834 685485
#  $ name  : Factor w/ 3 levels "john paul stevens",..: 2 3 1
```

As 'name' is `factor` class, the storage model is `integer`

```
df$name
#[1] john smith        willy mcghee      john paul stevens
# Levels: john paul stevens john smith willy mcghee
```

Or check the `levels`

```
levels(df$name)
#[1] "john paul stevens" "john smith"        "willy mcghee"
```

"john smith" is second level

```
df %>% 
  filter(name == "john smith") %>% 
  pull(name) %>% 
  as.integer
#[1] 2
```

While `paste`ing the `factor` got coerced to the integer storage mode

---

We need to `pull` the 'salary' column out of that to get a `vector` i.e.

```
vals$famousNetWorth <- df %>% 
               filter(name == input$people) %>%
               pull(salary)
```

-full code

```
salary <- c(45434,54834, 685485)
name <- c("john smith", "willy mcghee", "john paul stevens")
df <- data.frame(salary, name)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Title 
  titlePanel("title"),
  # this is the sidebar on the left when you run 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # selection of names
      selectInput("people",
                  label = "select the investor",
                  choices = c("john smith", "willy mcghee", "john paul stevens"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      helpText("main panel text"),
      textOutput("textsummary")
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    vals$people <- input$people
    vals$famousNetWorth <- df %>% 
                   filter(name == input$people) %>%
                   pull(salary)
  } )
  
  output$textsummary <- renderText({
    paste(" the salary for ",vals$people, " is ",   vals$famousNetWorth)
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: great explanation, this helped a ton, solved my problem exactly. thanks @akrun